# how to reschedule a repeatinterval notifications after letting the user to disable it temporarily?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, notifications, uilocalnotification

What's the best approach to implement "Do not disturb mode" into our apps? like letting the user choose to disable the notification between two periods.

Should I use the cancel method?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

any thoughts on specific component to be used are appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use a bool instance that will turn YES when the user sets to "do not disturb" and NO when it disable setting. Therefore, before posting notifications, you can control if "do not disturb" is on or off using the bool instance. You will be therefore able change the behaviour of your whole app. If you want to specify a period, use a timer that will trigger a method in which you can set the bool to NO and post the notification that should be posted while "do not disturb" was on.

Comment: thanks a lot.. do you have an example of timer trigger? or an idea on how to read from the date picker?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right idea. You will just need to find a separate way to store the potential notifications in the future and when the user toggles whatever you present as "do not disturb" in your app you would cancel all scheduled notifications and when they turn them back on you would just reset them all.

Comment: but, how about if I want it to reset them automatically without going back to the app again?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. If you are talking about connecting to the System Wide "do not disturb" then you don't have control. You will have to have the user open your app to reset any local notification you previously canceled. That said if the user is in do not disturb then I don't think you have to worry about any notification and just accept that the OS will protect them